# TYPO3 7.6 multilanguage - hidden pages cannot be seen in FE as a BE user

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

TYPO3 7.6.50

Requisites:

- A default page is created.
- An overlay page is created and is hidden.

Trying to visualize that hidden page in the frontend gives a:

```
Page Not Found
Reason: Page is not available in the requested language (strict).
```

Shouldn't the backend editor still see that page in the frontend as Preview?
I understand that for not logged in backend users, that Page not found error is right, but for backend users as well?

Answer (score 0):

is the translated version on the same domain than the backend?
session-cookies (BE-login) are stored domain dependend and so a BE-login can not be identified if the domain changes for a secondary language.

Solution:
login to the backend with the secondary language domain.